# Add annotation to plotOutput/renderPlot in Shiny without recomputing it

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny

I have a `ggplot2::geom_tile()` plot that takes dozens of seconds to render, so I don't want to have it re-rendered at all, but I do want to register click events (used with `shiny::nearPoints` to select what to show in some other plots) and ideally I'd like to have an annotation come up at the clicked location. Is it possible to add an overlay of some sort to show the clicked location?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up working out a solution whereby I use `ggplot2::layer_grob()` to compute the raster once, saving it, then adding it as a `annotation_raster` to the plot with other annotations on top whenever the latter needs to be updated:

```r
temp = ggplot(dat)+geom_raster(aes(x=x,y=y,fill=value))
raster = layer_grob(temp)$`1`$raster
p = (
    ggplot(dat)
    + annotation_raster(
        raster = raster
        , xmin = min(dat$x)
        , xmax = max(dat$x)
        , ymin = min(dat$y)
        , ymax = max(dat$y)
    )
)

#now p will re-render nearly instantly and you can add other geoms/annotations on top
```